# Defining a function. What is considered better: a complicated one-liner return or a simpler one-step-at-a-time definition?

Tags: python

Imagine I am defining a function (in this case it is in Python), which does some simple manipulations with a string and returns a string too. I can, for example, define it in two different ways, that will produce the same output:

```
    def signature(s):
    """Returns the signature of this string.
    Signature is a string that contains all of the letters in order.
    s: str
    """
    1) return ''.join(sorted(list(s)))
    2) t = list(s)
       t.sort()
       t = ''.join(t)
       return t
```

Is there a benefit to stick to any of these two ways in the long run? I have seen different developers practising both methods, but is it just a matter of taste?

Would appreciate any feedback to help me establish better programming habits.

Comment: Readability is a very subjective question. Who is reading your code - experienced Python devs, or beginners? I find shorter code easier to digest, but too dense can be confusing.

Comment: Btw, `return ''.join(sorted(s))` suffices

Comment: The shortest one will probably work better

Comment: Where is the *"complicated one-liner"*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, it's up to your project style guide.

This isn't a performance question, as both these statements take the same time to run, benchmark it if you'd like. Therefore, the difference is in syntax and syntax alone; and when choosing your syntax, it's best to conform to your styleguide.

If you're working in a corporate production setting, you could look around your project to find best practices. If you're working alone, you can decide which one you like better. Either way, consistency is the way to go when aiming for sustainable readability on your code.

The first statement reminds me personally of [Linq syntax](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-query-syntax), which aims make your code readable as is by chaining functions together. The second statement would be easier for a beginner to read, as the different functions are separated in their own lines.

As John specified in your comments, `return ''.join(sorted(s))` would suffice for what you're trying to do, and it's likely [one of the shortest ways](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12824/sorting-a-list-of-strings-without-using-any-built-in-sort-method/12828#12828) to implement this code.

If you want to read more about different style guides and creating your own, I'd recommend further reading about [linters](https://realpython.com/python-pep8/).

Answer (score 1):

There is a basic canon hidden in the `this` module. Execute

```
import this
```

to get it printed:

```
The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters

Beautiful is better than ugly.
Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex.
Complex is better than complicated.
Flat is better than nested.
Sparse is better than dense.
Readability counts.
Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
Although practicality beats purity.
Errors should never pass silently.
Unless explicitly silenced.
In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.
Now is better than never.
Although never is often better than *right* now.
If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!
```

See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/

Your example seems to fall under

```
Beautiful is better than ugly.
Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex.
Complex is better than complicated.
```

and would lead me to `return ''.join(sorted(s))` because `list(s)` is not needed as strings are iterables and can be fed into `sorted()` as is.

Comment: Nice reference, but I disagree with you. This is a readability matter, and he's asking how to make his code more readable. A beginner would say that spreading the different functions is more readable, explicit and beautiful. There isn't one answer here.

Comment: @A.Abramov  that would make this question closeable under the _Opinion-based_ reasoning. For the "explicit" version, any reader would need to understand _exactly_ (sorted() vs list.sort()) the same functions - spreading them out over multiple lines does not make it easier to understand them. It needs even one more line, because `list.sort() ` needs you to understand the conversion from string to list in addition to allother things. So for me beautiful and simple are definitly on the `return ''.join(sorted(s))` side.

Comment: No. This was originally commented on his question as an improvement to one of the statements, but he's not asking how to optimize these statements. It is an opinion based question: which is more readable; and there isn't one answer to that question.